# How to configure JSON jar files in jsp

Tags: json, jsp

How to configure JSON jar files in jsp?

I am getting error in `JSONObject` class.

In Java:

```
// Assuming 'request' is HttpServletRequest

String jsonString = request.getParameter("jsonData");
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: what is the issue now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

@user2866902 Do you have jar file in your classpath? Here i used json_simple-1.1.jar for my purpose. You need to import the jar file in jsp, like

```
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
```

Then you can get the json object like this,

```
<% net.sf.json.JSONObject responcedata = new net.sf.json.JSONObject(); %>
```

Hope this helps you..